# Clustering on Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualization, load-balancing, virtualhost, cluster

Can you cluster/load balance on a virtual machine?  I figured that would be redundant if the same machine is still performing the work but in virtual areas, or am I wrong?

Comment: Are you referring to techniques like [vSphere Fault Tolerance](http://www.vmware.com/products/fault-tolerance/overview.html) or is it "common" clustering techniques of applications and operating systems you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer would be probably - it depends. Depends on the virtualization platform you use and the required "clustering/load balancing" level. Could be network, server, application - specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can if your operating supports it, we did this to emulate a cluster once at college, but by no means is it better than just running the clustering software directly on your hardware platform.